# Реализация динамического двумерного массив как поле класса в С++

Tags: c++, классы, динамические-массивы

уважаемые участники сообщества! Недавно стал изучать С++.
Необходимо заполнить двумерный массив по диагонали. Решил выполнить задачу путем реализации динамического двумерного массива как поле класса. Иными другими способами задачу уже решил. Хочу именно с таким алгоритмом разобраться.
Компилятор выдает ошибку в 27 строке, в методе заполнения массива. Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Massive {
private:
    int** Mass;
    int Size;
public:

    Massive(int Size_of_Mass) {
        Size = Size_of_Mass;
        int** Mass = new int* [Size];
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            Mass[i] = new int[Size];
        }
    }
    void Mass_diag(int MAX) {                        // Метод заполнения массива по диагонали
        int k = 1;                                  // Первый элемент массива, индексы (0, 0)
        int z = 0;                                  // Счетчик строк
        while (k <= pow(MAX, 2)) {                  // Условие заполнения всех ячеек массива
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
                    if ((i + j) == z) {
                        Mass[j][i] = k;
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
            z++;
        }
    }
    void show(int MAX) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
                cout << setw(4) << Mass[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    system("chcp 1251 > NULL");
    int size;                                   // Размер массива
    cout << "Размерность массива: ";
    cin >> size;
    Massive objA(size);
    objA.Mass_diag(size);
    objA.show(size);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас главная ошибка не при заполнении, а вот тут:

```
    int** Mass = new int* [Size];
```

Т.е. вы создаете новую **локальную** переменную, которая не имеет никакого отношения к полю `Mass` в классе. Так что просто при заполнении вы пишете в непонятно какое место в памяти, UB со всеми вытекающими последствиями...

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я понял в чем дело, только пока не знаю как это реализовать  правильно. Буду воевать дальше,пока не получу результат!

Comment: Для начала в этой строчке убрать `int*`.

Comment: Вот только до VS добрался! Я так и хотел сделать! Тем самым мы не объявляем новую переменную, а используем указатель из поля Mass! Все работает! Спасибо! А цель такой реализации - записать разные способы заполнения массивов в виде методов в одном коде! Тем самым можно и наследование подключить будет, если потребует ввод новой переменной при другом способе заполнения массива.

Comment: И деструктор написать не забыть!